# How to power to negative number?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to power something to negative number but it always gives me NaN or Infinity.

How to make eg. 1.25^(-5) ?

Comment: Why don't you present the code which gives you that.

Comment: Did you see Math.pow()?

Comment: Ah, did you actually bitwise-XOR your FP operands? Yes, that explains your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(Math.pow(1.25, -5));
     }
}
```

prints:

> 0.32768

Here is a working [code snippet](http://goo.gl/rD293J)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Math.pow()` method

```
Math.pow(1.25, -5)
```