# How can i perform a "raise to the pow" for my Java Mortgage Code

Tags: java, math, calculator, pow

I'm trying to create a mortgage calculator in Java, but I'm having trouble with a math problem.
In essence, I need to raise to power a double but can't. I also tried (Math. pow) but it returns infinite since my exponent is a negative integer. Does anyone have any recommendations?

```
int n = 12;
int t = 30;
double r = 0.05;

int nt = n * t; // = 360
nt = -nt; // = -360

double principal = 1.0 - (1.0 + r / n); // = -0.004166666666666652

double result = Math.pow(principal, nt); // = Infinity

System.out.println(result);
```

Is there a way to raise `Principal` to the power of `nt`?

Comment: According to [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011012/5784924), you should be able to pass a negative exponent to the `Math.pow` function. Your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: What are `r` and `n`? Please create a [mre].

Comment: Your code 'works' for me if I assume  `int n = 2; double r = 0.1; int t = 10;` but the result is very large `1.0485759999999814E26
`.   I second the call for a reproducible example.

Comment: I don't undersfand what you're calculating, either.  (And a variable called 'Half' that does not appear to be half of anything else in the program does not help)

Comment: I edited it i hope its readable now

Comment: I see 2 potential issues with your code: Firstly, please follow Java naming conventions (give your variable names `lowerCaseNames`, i. e. `Half` should be named `half`). Secondly, mind your data types. `1` is an `int`, not a double. So, if `r` and `n` are also `int`s, you are actually doing an integer calculation in `Double Half = 1 -(1 + r/n);` and only casting it at the end of the calculation, potentially causing huge rounding errors.

Comment: ALso, you should avoid using boxed classes for primitive types (i. e. use `double` instead of `Double`)

Comment: ok thanks for the advice

Comment: is the math alright? i saw `-0.004166666666666652` powered to `-360.0`, no wonder java gave up. also, `1 -(1 + r/n)` doesnt that meant `1 - 1 - r/n` which basically `-r/n`?

Comment: curious question, i feel i've seen something similar to this formula somewhere. are you trying to calculate compound interest?

Comment: I am trying to calculate mortgage yes

Comment: and yes that is the proper equation when calculated on a calculator the answer is = 0.7761734044

Comment: @Tomibell Bagus is not wrong. Plug -r/n into your calculator and you'll find that's the same number as your convoluted `1.0 - (1.0 + r / n)`.

Comment: @tomibell __it is not the right formula__. Just read your code (don't run it), and calculate along. As you say, `principal` is -0.004166666. `nt` is -360. a tiny negative number to a humongous negative power is __obviously__ infinity, and it _definitely_ is not .7761734. [Here is your result done with a proper calculator: See, infinity; a number with 856 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-.05%2F12%29+%5E+-360).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to lie in your maths, not the call to `Math.pow()`, which works perfectly fine for negative exponents: `Math.pow(10, -2)` leads to `0.01`, which is exactly what we want. Therefore, let's backtrack:

The debugger tells us that `principal` evaluates to `-0.004166666666666652` and `nt` evaluates to `-360`. What you are therefore trying to calculate is the following:

```
double result = Math.pow(-0.004166666666666652, -360); // = Infinity
```

which is mathematically equivalent to

```
double result = 1.0 / Math.pow(-0.004166666666666652, 360) // = Infinity
```

Now, if you just look at `Math.pow(-0.004166666666666652, 360)`, you are taking a fraction whose value is between `-1.0` and `0.0` and raise that to a very high power (in this case `360`). What happens to a fraction that is in the interval `]-1.0; 1.0[` and that is raised to such a high power is that it approaches `0.0` the higher the exponent is (mathematically speaking [image: limit of x^n with x approaching -0 = 0] with `n >> 0`).

Your math therefore becomes

[image: result = 1 / -0.004166666666666652^360 approximately equals 1 / 0 approximately equals Infinity]

Your math therefore must be wrong somewhere, and in fact, if you look at the [video that you linked in a comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5cw1xc8pTw), the formula that you need to use is the following:

[image: result = 1 - (1 + r / n)^-nt]

but what you implemented is

[image: result = (1 - (1 + r / n))^-nt]

I hope you see where the issue is now and wish you good luck with the exercise :)

**Edit:** Using the correct formula, your code should look like this:

```java
int n = 12;
int t = 30;
double r = 0.05;

double result = 1.0 - Math.pow(1.0 + r / n, -n * t);

System.out.println(result);

// Example from the video for comparison
System.out.println(1.0 - Math.pow(1.00416666666666666666, -360));
```

which prints `0.7761734043586468` for both, the example from the video and the result of the code.

Comment: Holy shit thanks so much it works!!!!!!!!!!!. I am grateful for the help.

Comment: That's great to hear :) Would you mind to upvote my answer and mark it as the solution using the checkmark left to the answer? That would be great as it gives you and me a reputation boost. Cheers :)

Comment: hey i marked it as the answer but don't have enough points to upvote a post

Comment: @tomibell now you have the points.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage in, garbage out. Your code describes a process that leads to Infinity. In other words, the answer to the question:

How can i perform a "raise to the pow" for my Java Mortgage Code

Is: **Exactly how you are doing it**.

Hence, there's an underlying problem: You have failed to program a compound calculation.

What you're actually looking for is:

```
(1 + r/n)^nt.
```

You've adde a `1.0 - ...` somewhere. Don't do that. You've also added a - to `nt` for some reason. Don't do that either:

```
int n = 12;
int t = 30;
double r = 0.05;

int nt = n * t; // = 360
// nt = -nt; // = -360 DO NOT DO THIS

// double principal = 1.0 - (1.0 + r / n); // = -0.004166666666666652
double principal = 1.0 + r / n;

double result = Math.pow(principal, nt);

System.out.println(result);
```

This prints 4.467744314006109.

Which is correct: If you invest X euros in a getup that pays out 5% interest a year, paid out monthly, and you keep it invested for 12 years, you end up with slightly less than 4.5x the invested amount.

Comment: This is wrong, i am trying to calculate Mortgage not compound Intrest this is the formula I am following(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5cw1xc8pTw).

Comment: The formula you are attempting to write is the compound interest formula. The way you wrote it, the answer __is__ infinity, you're asking: "How do I do pow?" - you did it, and java gave you the correct answer - infinity.